# How to make a pie chart in an Android app

Tags: android, firebase

[image: please describe how I can develop]

I can develop this type of chart but I can't understand how I am develop it.

Comment: Your title mentions a pie chart, but you have a bar chart in your question body. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using this library for creating charts:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart